# Determiners: This and that. Has “that” replaced “this”?

Tags: pronouns, determiners, this-that

I'm confused. As far as I know, ***this*** is reserved for something that is right ahead of speakers and/or speakers talk about that item the whole conversation. ***That*** is reserved for something that is not exactly right here.

But in different literature I see “that” all the time, even though sometimes it's more appropriate to use “this”.

Has “that” replaced “this”?
When to use “this” and “that”?

Comment: No, _that_ has not 'replaced' _this_. You need to give an example of where you think the word has been incorrectly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has that replaced this?

Of course not.

1. **This**- pronoun, demonstrative adjective, and determiner is used with the object/person that

(i) is new -> Introduction: *“This is my sister.”*

(ii)    the first thing ->  *“This first example is very valuable”*

(iii)   is being experienced presently and ‘for the first time’ -> *“This is my first time in Africa.”*

(iv)    is the only thing being presently discussed/experienced -> *“You have described the main idea, concept, thing, person; This could be worth a fortune.” “Nowadays, a lot of young women want to have plastic surgery. This has become a social issue in my country.*

(v) will be immediately discussed/experienced, -> *“I would like some more information on this idea of yours.”*

(vi)    Is the nearest thing (in space or time) -> *“This ring in my hand is very expensive.”*

(vii)   Is the thing now indicated -> *“Moving on, if I may show you this. [points at something]…”*

2. **That** pronoun, demonstrative adjective, and determiner is the object/person that

(i) has been discussed/experienced, -> *“I told you about that yesterday!”*

(ii)    is the next and subsequent thing, -> *“This pin is rusty, now let’s look at that one."*

(iii)   was experienced in the past  ->  *“I went to Zambia in 1987. That was my first time in Africa.”*

(iv)    is the second or subsequent thing being discussed/experienced -> *"You have told me about your experience in Africa, but you also went to America, tell me about that."*

(v) a more distant object in space or time->   *“That over there is my shopping list.” / “Ah yes, 1950… that was the year I went to Brazil.”*

**This** and **that** are deictic pronouns, and they are involved in contexts of "distance" and "pointing:" This is my dog (I'm "pointing" to my dog, which is close to me); That is my house (I'm "pointing" to the house, which is at some distance from me).